# saveAsync on outlook appointment with attendees throws error

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Calling saveAsync on an Outlook for Mac calendar appt with attendees throws an error. An appt without attendees processes fine.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function (asyncResult) { itemId = asyncResult.value; });
```

[saveAsync error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHafg.png)

Comment: Accepting Answers: [How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

Saving meeting (Appointment with attendees) as draft is not supported in Mac outlook.
Documented here - https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/compare-outlook-add-in-support-in-outlook-for-mac?product=outlook